# When i run my program the simulator only shows the "people" section but not the "videos" section

Tags: swift, xcode8

Hi I'm new to coding and I am trying to display some information onto the simulator but unfortunately when i run the program the simulator only displays the people section of the program but not the videos section

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    let people = [
        ("Bucky Roberts", "New York"),
        ("Lisa Tucker", "Alabama"),
        ("Emma Hotpocket", "Texas")

    ]

    let videos = [
        ("Andriod App Development", "74 videos"),
        ("C++ for Beginners", "87 videos"),
        ("Java", "142 videos"),
        ("Python Programming", "63 videos"),
        ("Web Design", "68 videos")

    ]
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int {
        if index == 0{
        return people.count
        }else{
            return videos.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = UITableViewCell()

        if indexPath.section == 0{
            var (personName, personLocation) = people[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = personName
        }else{
            var (videoTitle, videoDesc) = videos[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = videoTitle
        }
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if section == 0{
            return "People"
        }else{
            return "Videos"
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

Comment: is it working now ?

Comment: You are welcome, it would be great if the answer is accepted !

Answer (score 1):

Add `numberOfSections` to your `tableView`

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 2 // for people and videos

}
```